# Designing multiple types of payment schema in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, database-design, rdbms

I've payment system where I can do two types of payment for an order.

1. Online -  Mobile payment
2. Offline - Cash/ Cheque

I've credited 4 tables, I'm outlining only important columns not everything for simplicity.

```
List of table Names

Payment
CashPaymentDetails
ChequePaymentDetails
MobilePaymentDetails

Schema Details

CashPaymentDetails
cash_id int
cash_amount decimal(18,2)

ChequePaymentDetails
cheque_id int
cheque_amount decimal(18,2)
cheque_type

MobilePaymentDetails
mobile_id int
mobile_amount decimal(18,2)

Payment
payment_id int
payment_amount  decimal(18,2)
fk_cash_id int (foreign key reference to CashPaymentDetails table)
fk_cheque_id (foreign key reference to ChequePaymentDetails table)
fk_mobile_id (foreign key reference to MoblePaymentDetails table)
```

User can do either cash/cheque/mobile, only one payment mode, this makes my two foreign keys NULL which i feel is overhead because if going forward I've 10 different types of payment method, 9 Fk references will be NULL.

Payment

```
Payment_id payment_amount fk_cash_id fk_cheque_id fk_mobile_id
1 300 1 NULL NULL
2 200 NULL 1 NULL
3 400 NULL NULL 1
```

what should be an optimal design to create this schema?

Comment: Why multiple tables.  I would stick with PaymentType, ReferenceNbr, and Amount

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Multiple tables because cheque has some info (chequetype, date, IFSC) which cash doesn't have and mobile has transferRefNo which cash/cheque doesn't have. Different tables would help me to separate related information efficiently.

Comment: Fair enough, you know your data and requirements better than anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Create table for PaymentMethod and refer its PK in Payments table then according to payment method you can make appropriate entry in respective tables of payment method. I have also added Payment_id in [CashPaymentDetails],  [ChequePaymentDetails] & [MobilePaymentDetails] tables.

```
Schema Details

[PaymentMethods]
Payment_Method_id int
Payment_Method_Description varchar(50)  --  ("cash", "cheque", "mobile" etc)

[Payment]
Payment_id int
Payment_Method_id int
payment_amount  decimal(18,2)


[CashPaymentDetails]
cash_id int
payment_id int
cash_amount decimal(18,2)

[ChequePaymentDetails]
cheque_id int
payment_id int
cheque_amount decimal(18,2)
cheque_type

[MobilePaymentDetails]
mobile_id int
payment_id int
mobile_amount decimal(18,2)
```

Comment: You may want to add Payment_Method_ID to the various details table and use it with Payment_ID as a foreign key to the Payment table (include Payment_Method_ID there with Payment_ID in a unique index to make this possible). Then it becomes impossible to insert, say, a cheque detail for a payment defined as cash, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Your design is fine (not the only choice, but fine).  I would add a constraint to the table to ensure that one -- and exactly one -- payment type is implemented:

```
alter table payment
    add constraint chk_one_payment
        check ((fk_cash_id is not null and fk_cheque_id is null and fk_mobile_id is null) or
              (fk_cash_id is null and fk_cheque_id is not null and fk_mobile_id is null) or
              (fk_cash_id is null and fk_cheque_id is null and fk_mobile_id is not null)
             );
```

There are other ways to represent a one-of relationship.  For instance, you could just have:

- PaymentType (one of "cash", "cheque", "mobile")
- PaymentAmount
- CheckType (if applicable)

The different types of payments have almost the same columns, so this is very reasonable in your case.  For some one-of relationships, the different types have very different columns, and want to be in their own tables.

Comment: Going forward if i add 10 different payment methods, so 9 Fk columns will be NULL, this is more overhead.

Comment: @user614978 . . . True, but that isn't the question you asked.

Answer (score -1):

My advice is this. 
On the Payment table, remove all those foreign keys and add these 2 fields.

```
processor_type enum['bank', 'cheque', 'card']
transaction_id fk to the processor table.
```

With this, each time you update/add a new processor, you just need to update the enum such that it takes the new set of payment processors. The transaction_id is a foreign key to the appropriate table depending on the processor_type.

If you are using laravel, you can make use of polymorphic relationships
That's my suggestion.